# Describe the open sets in the topology $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)$

Tags: general-topology

From Topology Without Tears:

Let $S$ be the collection of all the circles in the plane.If $S$ is a subbasis for  a topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.Describe the open sets in $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)$.

For two different circles,their intersection will be either one point or two points.So,considering intersection of all two possible circles that intersect at a single point,the basis will include singleton sets $\{r\} ,\forall r\in \mathbb{R}^2$

So,our topology is discrete topology.so,all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ will be open.Am I correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any point in the plane is the kissing point of two circles, i.e. their intersection.  Looks good!  Since the topology generated by a sub-basis is all unions of finite intersections, we are done.